# sender void value as into antoher void

Tags: c#

i have a question, that how can I but long code into void, that has "sender" and "KeyPressEventArgs" and afterwards use this void in many other voids. For example:

```
private void Value_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //I want my void shortcut here
        CheckValue(???);
    }
```

This is my void, where from i want my code

```
private virtual void CheckValue(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
        var stringToFind = "";
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)8)
        {
            if (comboBox.SelectionStart <= 1)
            {
                comboBox.Text = "";
                return;
            }

            if (comboBox.SelectionLength == 0)
                stringToFind = comboBox.Text.Substring(0, comboBox.Text.Length - 1);
            else
                stringToFind = comboBox.Text.Substring(0, comboBox.SelectionStart - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            if (comboBox.SelectionLength == 0)
                stringToFind = comboBox.Text + e.KeyChar;
            else
                stringToFind = comboBox.Text.Substring(0, comboBox.SelectionStart) + e.KeyChar;
        }
        var indexOfFoundString = -1;
        // Search the string in the ComboBox list.
        indexOfFoundString = comboBox.FindString(stringToFind);
        if (indexOfFoundString != -1)
        {
            comboBox.SelectedText = "";
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = indexOfFoundString;
            comboBox.SelectionStart = findString.Length;
            comboBox.SelectionLength = comboBox.Text.Length;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
            e.Handled = true;
```

I really hope, you understood my problem and can give me answer :)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here, but maybe you need `CheckValue(sender, e);`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I can't tell.

Comment: While "My Void" would be a nice title for an emo song, it has basically no meaning in the context. The [void keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yah0tteb.aspx) means that the method does not return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  CheckValue(sender,  e);
```

pass this (may be that is what u r asking.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mean function and not `void` the latter is an indication of `no value` 
The easiest way is to assign the same function to the event handler E.g.

```
control1.KeyPressed += CheckValue
control2.KeyPressed += CheckValue
```

or to stay true to your code you can simply call the function. There's nothing special about the functions used as event handlers so they can be called from anywhere just as any other function can

```
private void Value_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //I want my void shortcut here
    CheckValue(sender,e);
}
```